# url rewrite, nginx throw 404 errors, nothing in error logs

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite, regex, http-status-code-404

below rewrite works fine:

```
rewrite ^/city/restaurants$ /city/listings/restaurants permanent;
```

but this doesnt work

```
rewrite ^/city/restaurants$ /city/listings/restaurants last;
rewrite ^/city/restaurants$ /city/listings/restaurants break;
```

what am i doing wrong?

below entire nginx server block

```
  server {
          listen 80 default backlog=1024;
          server_name mydomain.com;


          client_max_body_size 20M;
          charset utf-8;
          keepalive_timeout 50;

          access_log /var/log/access_log main;
          error_log /var/log/error_log info;


          root /var/www/;
          index index.php index.phtml index.html;
  autoindex on;

   location ~ \..*/*\.php$ {
       return 403;
   }
   location ~^/sites/.*/private/{
       return 403;
   }
   location ~^/sites/.*/files/* {
       try_files $uri @rewrite;
   }
   location ~ (^|/)\. {
       return 403;
   }

   location / {

rewrite ^/city/restaurants$ /city/listings/restaurants last;

    location ~* \.php$ {
                            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                            #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                            #try_files $uri @rewrite;
                            }
                    try_files $uri @rewrite;
                    }

            location @rewrite {
                    rewrite ^ /index.php;
            }
            location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$
            {
                    try_files $uri $uri/;
                    expires 30d;

             }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, move the key rewrite out of the `location` block into the enclosing `server` block. That will simplify your logic.

Next, [enable rewrite debug logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/333048/best-way-to-debug-nginx-config-file) to confirm if the 404 you are getting is from the original URL, or the rewritten URL.

Finally, if the root cause is still not found [enable general debug logging](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) for Nginx:

```
error_log /path/to/log debug;
```